# Block access to files in a directory but allow index.html

Tags: nginx

I'm hosting a website on /test/ but files can be accessed by going to the url if user knows filename. Ex:

```
domain.com/test/readmesample.txt
```

I have it setup like above but now when i go to domain.com/test the index.html file wont load and I get a 403 forbidden.

How can i set it up so when going to /test it allows the html file to load while still blocking files inside that directory? This includes files, folders and .files other than index.html.

```
location ~ /test {
             deny all;
}
```

Here is my config file

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl default_server;

root /config/www;
index index.html index.htm index.php;

server_name www.domain.com;

ssl_certificate /config/keys/letsencrypt/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /config/keys/letsencrypt/privkey.pem;
ssl_dhparam /config/nginx/dhparams.pem;
ssl_ciphers 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

client_max_body_size 0;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php?$args =404;

}

location ~ /new {
    deny all;

}       


location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # With php5-cgi alone:
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # With php5-fpm:
    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: does that help?
http://serverfault.com/questions/222854/set-nginx-conf-to-deny-all-connections-except-to-certain-files-or-directories
?

Comment: It's confusing. Sorry, I'm still learning nginx so this is all new to me.

Answer (score 4):

You can explicitly break out `/test/index.html` with:

```
location = /test/index.html {
}
location ^~ /test {
    deny all;
}
```

The exact match location has highest precedence, and the `^~` modifier places the precedence of the prefix location above regular expression locations at the same level.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

Comment: Adding that allows the html file from /test to load but does not block access to the files inside the directory. Maybe i'm doing it wrong?

Comment: @jrdnic - Richard Smith's answer is one correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out not sure if it's the proper way but it works. Feel free to correct me

```
location /test {
location ~ \.(txt|gif|jpg|png)$ {
      deny all;
      }
      }
```

Using that blocks access to all those extensions in /test and inside any sub directory.

Comment: Thank you!  Did the same for disallowing .map files on Javascript -- works like a charm!

Comment: It doesn't answer you own question.  It also allows many other files besides index.html

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `return 444`; than `deny all`; 
Deny all show server name

[Nginx configuration disallow or allow files access](https://pceuropa.net/blog/nginx-disallow-file-access/)

Comment: You're correct. I have changed it to `return 444;` Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Richard Smith's answer is correct.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42560939/4376643)  Here is another correct answer:

```
location ^~ /test {
    try_files /test/index.html =404
}
```

Comment: @hcheung - thanks, changed `try` to `try_files` - nginx has no `try` command, it was my input mistake.